# NHibernate on-delete="cascade" with relationship on many side

Tags: nhibernate, one-to-many, cascade

I have an object model like that:

- `Folder` - simple structure with name etc.
- `File` - complex object containing reference to `Folder` in which it is contained.

**Folder doesn't know its Files** and I don't want it to know. The relation is *many-to-one* and should be known on File's side only.

Anyway, I would like to rely on my database's ON DELETE CASCADE feature, so that **when I remove Folder, I want all Files within that Folder to be deleted** automatically. I can't use NHibernate's cascading as there is no relation from Folder to File.

I know that [there is `on-delete="cascade"` option](http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/12/nhibernate-20-and-cascading-deletes-2/) for `<key>` element in case of *one-to-many* relationship, but I can't find its equivalent for my model - when the relation is **defined on *many* side**.

Am I doing something wrong or do I really need to go through and delete all the Files within deleted Folder manually?

Comment: Just to be sure: You know that the `on-delete` attribute does nothing at runtime but only affects the hbm2ddl tool? And you are using the tool to generate the DB schema?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use database-level cascading. You're right, it has to be generated by hbm2ddl. Is it possible for my relation or do I need to modify the database manually?

Comment: if cascade="all-delete-orphan" then session.Delete(folder); would automaticly delete all Files associated with the folder. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that Folder doesn't know its Files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to map the one-to-many side with `access="noop"`. That way you don't need a property in your classes but still have the mapping.

In Fluent NHibernate that would be someting like this:

```
HasMany(Reveal.Member<Folder, IEnumerable<File>>("_files"))
   .KeyColumn("column_name")
   .Access.NoOp()
   .Inverse()
   .ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete();
```

Note: For that you need an `_files` field of type `IEnumerable<File>` in the `Folder` class (limitation of Fluent NHibernate, can only map really existing fields or properties). But this field can always be `null`, it will never be used.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you maybe have an idea is it possible to map it using FluentNHibernate?

Comment: @A.. I've edited my answer to show a Fluent NHibernate mapping.